# Can't inject service to controller angularJs + CordovaJs (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, typescript

I have application angularJs + CordovaJs + TypeScript
I try to inject service to controller

```
module EC {
export class Bootstrap {
constructor($scope) {
  angular.module('ec', ['ec.services', 'ec.controllers']);
  angular.module('ec.services', []);
  angular.module('ec.controllers', []);

  //Constructor for class EC.Services.DataProxyService called
  angular.module('ec.services').factory("DataProxyService", EC.Services.DataProxyService);

  //Version 1
  // It is not working. Alert doesn't call
  angular.module('ec.controllers').controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'DataProxyService', EC.Controllers.HomeController]);

  //Version 2
  //If I change previous on that
  //it work's but I don't have access to DataProxyService
  //angular.module('ec.controllers').controller("HomeController", ['$scope', EC.Controllers.HomeController]);
    }
  }
}
```

Call this class in separate javascript file (index.js)

```
   var init = new EC.Bootstrap();
```

I very confused because it must work but it doesn't work on android device (mobile phone) and android emulator

I tried to use a lot of variants but they didn't work too and anyway this case must work

I have problem with debug this code I can't get error but simple angular piece doesn't work for version 1 and work for version 2

UPD: 2
I use gulp so I get next file as result:

```
    /// <reference path="references.ts" />
var EC;
(function (EC) {
    var Bootstrap = (function () {
        function Bootstrap($scope) {
            angular.module('ec', ['ec.services', 'ec.controllers']);
            angular.module('ec.services', []);
            angular.module('ec.controllers', []);
            //Constructor for class EC.Services.DataProxyService called
            angular.module('ec.services').factory("DataProxyService", EC.Services.DataProxyService);
            //Version 1
            // It is not working. Alert doesn't call
            angular.module('ec.controllers').controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'DataProxyService', EC.Controllers.HomeController]);
            //Version 2
            //If I change previous on that
            //it work's but I don't have access to DataProxyService
            //angular.module('ec.controllers').controller("HomeController", ['$scope', EC.Controllers.HomeController]);
        }
        return Bootstrap;
    })();
    EC.Bootstrap = Bootstrap;
})(EC || (EC = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=boot.js.map
//// <reference path="../scripts/typings/tsd.d.ts" />
//// <reference path="../../typings/kendo.all.d.ts" />
//// <reference path="../../typings/api.d.ts" />
//# sourceMappingURL=references.js.map
/// <reference path="../references.ts" />
var EC;
(function (EC) {
    var Controllers;
    (function (Controllers) {
        var HomeController = (function () {
            /*@ngInject*/
            function HomeController($scope, dataProxyService) {
                this.name = "Smith";
                alert('HomeController');
                alert($scope);
                alert(dataProxyService);
                $scope.vm = this;
            }
            return HomeController;
        })();
        Controllers.HomeController = HomeController;
    })(Controllers = EC.Controllers || (EC.Controllers = {}));
})(EC || (EC = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=home-controller.js.map
/// <reference path="../references.ts" />
var EC;
(function (EC) {
    var Services;
    (function (Services) {
        var DataProxyService = (function () {
            /*@ngInject*/
            function DataProxyService() {
                alert('DataProxyService');
            }
            return DataProxyService;
        })();
        Services.DataProxyService = DataProxyService;
    })(Services = EC.Services || (EC.Services = {}));
})(EC || (EC = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=dataProxyService.js.map
```

Comment: where are you defining `EC.Services.DataProxyService`

Comment: In one file with other/ I added to start message example of code which I get after "gulp"

Comment: where are you defining the `ec.services` module. e.g. angular.module('ec.services', [])

Comment: sorry, I made a lot of experiments with code and I lost important strings

I update post and I fixed up code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
module EC {
  export class Bootstrap {
constructor($scope) {
  angular.module('EC', []);
  angular.module('Services', []);

  //Constructor for class EC.Services.DataProxyService called
  angular.module('Services').service("DataProxyService", [Services.DataProxyService]);

  //Version 1
  // It is not working. Alert doesn't call
  angular.module('EC', ['Services']).controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'DataProxyService', Controllers.HomeController]);

  //Version 2
  //If I change previous on that
  //it work's but I don't have access to DataProxyService
  //angular.module('ec.controllers').controller("HomeController", ['$scope', EC.Controllers.HomeController]);
}  }}
```

Change module name to simple name like "Service" and "Controller" in *.ts files